# Python3.4-How to take a number out of a list and change to a float for math

Tags: python, list, variables, math, typeerror

I have a list of numbers inputted by a user. I need to be able to point to a spot in my list. Take that number thats there, add to it, and put the new number in its place. However no matter how many different ways I try this it always tells me "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'". Here is the code I have thus far

> ItemsAmt ##This is the list
>
> ItemsAmtIn ##A Number inputted by the user
>
> ItemsAmtIn2 ##I added this variable in an attempt to extract the
>   number and change to a float

```
if ItemsIn == 1:
        ItemsAmt[0]
        ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt
        ItemsAmtIn = ItemsAmtIn + ItemsAmtIn2
        ItemsAmt.insert(0,ItemsAmtIn)
        ItemCost = .89 * ItemsAmtIn
        Cost.insert(0,ItemCost)
        TotalCost = TotalCost + ItemCost
```

Comment: ItemCost is a list, TotalCost is an int, you can't add them together. The error message is pretty clear

Comment: ItemCost is not a list and the code doesnt even get to that point before it errors out.

Comment: ItemsAmtIn = ItemsAmtIn + ItemsAmtIn2
###is the line it errors on

Comment: `ItemsAmtIn + ItemsAmtIn2` then

Comment: This statement doesnt do anything `ItemsAmt[0]` perhaps you meant `ItemsAmt = ItemsAmt[0]`?

Comment: `ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt` is setting `ItemsAmtIn2` to a list. Your call of `ItemsAmt[0]` above that doesn't do anything, as you haven't stored the result in a variable. Is your intended result : `ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt[0]`?

Comment: ItemsAmtIn is not a list, ItemsAmtIn2 is also not a list. Or if for some reason it is making ItemsAmtIn2 a list because of "ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt" then thats still my same question. How do I take a number out of this list to do math with and put it back.

Comment: Okay, The first point(0) in this list is currently zero. I'm trying to take that zero, lets say add 10 to it, so now its 10. If the user decides to add the same item again, lets say 20, I need to be able to take that 10, add 20, put the 30 in its place. And use the 30 to find the cost for a different variable/list

Comment: "ItemsAmtIn2 is also not a list"; yet you assign it to `ItemsAmt`, which is a list. "Taking a number out of a list" is the same as accessing it, which is exactly what you do in `ItemsAmt[0]` (but then you don't do anything with that number).

Comment: `ItemsAmt = [ItemsAmt[0] + ItemsAmtIn] + ItemsAmt` does what you have now in the first 4 lines. But you probably want `ItemsAmt[0] += ItemsAmtIn`. Perhaps it's a good idea to (re)read some Python tutorials; this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Ah yes that worked perfectly. It may be basic sure, I am in a basic programming class after all :) Still trying to understand how lists work fully. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt
```

you declared ItemsAmtIn2 as a identical copy of ItemsAmt. So ItemsAmtIn2 ***becomes*** a list as well as ItemsAmt is.

If Tim Castelijns is right with his presumption **ItemsAmt[0]** meant to be **ItemsAmt = ItemsAmt[0]** then you probably meant **ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt** to be

```
ItemsAmtIn2 = ItemsAmt[0]
```